# $_REQUEST not returning value from URL

Tags: php, url, request

My url is this

http://localhost/lahore/electronics.html?page=3

My code to receive page number is this

```
echo $pageno = $_REQUEST['page'];
```

It should be return value 3, but its display empty result.
any best solution to get page number from this URL.

**Note:** Its PHP page I use .httaccess to convert PHP extention  into HTML.
Can i use any other way to get page number ?

Comment: HTML pages can't accept parameters. You have to use PHP page instead like http://localhost/lahore/electronics.php?page=3

Comment: paste your full code here..

Comment: Your file has a `.html` extension. It is unlikely that your server is configured to parse it for PHP. The PHP source code will probably show up if you make use of View Source in your browser. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Its PHP page I use .httaccess to convert php into html

Comment: Can i use any other way to get page number ?

Comment: You need to post your `.htaccess` file to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Either (1) Your attempt to process `.html` files as PHP doesn't work at all or (2) Your attempt is stripping off the query string before it gets to PHP. Either way you need to edit your question to show what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your script seem like an html document, not a php script.

Comment: Its PHP page I use .httaccess to convert PHP extention  into HTML

Comment: @OnlineBazaarPkBazaar.pk Is the apache's rewrite rule is correct? May be apache does not pass the query string to php.

Comment: Can i use any other way to get page number ??